# How to query Delta Lake tables with some simple setup like DBeaver?

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I am using Apache Spark and Delta lake tables as sink.
But need some simple setup which can be used to analyze my processed data with queries on top of delta lake.
for eg. How can I setup DBeaver to query my delta tables which are setup locally ?
And likewise any other method is welcome.

Comment: Unlike other databases, Delta lake does not have server side where you can send query to (it is what DBeaver does - sends queries to server and renders results) so you need smth which will **execute** queries rather than send them somewhere. Spark is what can execute queries, so you can setup and use it locally. Here is guide from Delta docs https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#set-up-interactive-shell

Comment: hmm. My agenda was to make it available to anyone without a need of opening spark as such as we already have processed parquet files.

Comment: Look, if you install DBeaver, then you do not get ability to "query files". You get ability to connect to some **existing** DB server which supports JDBC protocol. Delta lake does not have server, so you need something which will act as a server, e.g. Spark.

Comment: When you have local Spark, then you can use Jupiter Notebook as the UI, e.g. https://medium.com/sicara/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f